# Replace Function of pandas Giving same value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to replace a Number from .csv row with some constant string value. But somehow the code rewrites entire content of csv but doesn't replace it.

I have tried using delimiter but didn't work.

```
newfile = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter = ',')
for B in Testnumber:
    files=newfile.replace(to_replace = B,value ="BlacklistedNumber")
    files.to_csv(file,index=False)
```

The expected result is the number in list Testnumber to replaced by BlaclistedNumber.
[Sample CSV Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDACU.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your logic. For each B, files is newly generated from newfile, so any previous changes made are overwritten. A better solution would be:

```
newfile = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',')
for B in Testnumber:
    newfile = newfile.replace(to_replace=B, value="BlacklistedNumber")
newfile.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it to string and then pass into replace regex=True, also use this code instead of for loop

```
newfile = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter = ',')
files=newfile.astype(str).replace(to_replace = Testnumber,value =["BlacklistedNumber"]*len(Testnumber),regex=True)
files.to_csv(file,index=False)
```

It will replace all numbers of the list Testnumber with the string BlacklistedNumber